# store image as blob and display on html

Tags: php, mysql

I met an issue during building a website.

> - lang: php, js, html
> - dbms: mysql

What I am trying to do

1. load an user avatar (image) from database that is stored as blob within a user record
2. get it displaying on my html webpage

---

In the website:

1. user uploading image as avatar is achieved by

```html
<input id="avatar" type="file" />
```

```js
const avatar = document.getElementById('avatar');

$.ajax({
    url: '../php/action.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: `image=${avatar.value}&action=uploadAvatar`
});
```

2. in user class

```php
class User{ 
    protected $id;
    protected $avatar; // blob
    // ...

    function setId($id) { $this->id = $id; }
    function getId() { return $this->id; }
    function setAvatar($avatar) { $this->avatar = $avatar; }
    function getAvatar() { return $this->avatar; }
    // ...
}
```

3. the avatar is stored only when the record is created. which user can only set avatar during registration.

```php
function dummy_user($image){
    $user1 = new User(); 
    $user1->setAvatar($image);
    // ...
}

dummy_user($_POST['image']);
```

in user class, `sql` is parsed and executed as:

```php
$sql = "INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `avatar` ...) VALUES ('" . strval($this->getId()) . "', '" . $this->getAvatar() . " ... ')";
// some other values are omitted by ellipsis
```

4. to load record from database

```php
// exceptions and error handling are omitted
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE id = ' . strval($id) . '');
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

5. however, for result collected in javascript

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '../php/action.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: "id=1&action=loadUser"
}).done(function(result){
    var res = JSON.parse(result);
    console.log(res);
});
```

I get this:

```
{"id":"1","avatar":"C:fakepathhusky.png" ...}
```

there are few things worth mentioning:

- database user table avatar field is set as blob. The initial image size before uploading is `349kb`
- after uploading to database, the blob is `19b`
- image name: `husky.png`

6. to render the image to html page

```js
// result collected from php by ajax
var res = JSON.parse(result);
let img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa(res.avatar));
```

I ended up with failue. The expected result is to get the image displaying in html page. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't upload a file with Ajax, you can only upload files with Ajax through formdata

Wrap your file input with form tag like so:

```
<form id="avatar">
<input name="image" type="file" />
</form>
```

Rewrite your Ajax code like so:

```
const form = document.getElementById('avatar');
const formdt = new FormData(form);

$.ajax({
url: '../php/action.php',
method: 'POST',
data: formdt,
processData: false, 
contentType: false
})
```